# sql query to find absent list with date in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two attendance tables.One is`employeelist` and another is `attendence_info`.`Employeelist contain Emp_Id and Emp_name`. `Attendance_info is Emp_Id, Date`.As below:

```
Emp_ID      Date
----------- -----------------------
1         2014-12-11 00:00:00.000
2         2014-12-11 00:00:00.000
4         2014-12-11 00:00:00.000
5         2014-12-11 00:00:00.000
2         2014-12-10 00:00:00.000
4         2014-12-10 00:00:00.000
5         2014-12-10 00:00:00.000
1         2014-12-09 00:00:00.000
2         2014-12-09 00:00:00.000
3         2014-12-09 00:00:00.000
```

Here each date some id are absent. I want to find out all absent list with date.Please help to find it by Sql server query. My desired output should be as below:

```
   absentId       Date
    3         2014-12-11 00:00:00.000
    1         2014-12-10 00:00:00.000
    3         2014-12-10 00:00:00.000
    4         2014-12-09 00:00:00.000
    5         2014-12-09 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.Emp_ID as absentId,a.Date as date
from employeelist e
join attendence_info a
on e.Emp_ID=a.Emp_ID
order by a.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by generating a list of all employees and dates and then removing the ones where the employee is present.  This is basically a `cross join` and `left join`:

```
select el.emp_id, d.date
from (select distinct date from Attendance_info) d cross join
     employeelist el left join
     Attendance_info ai
     on ai.date = d.date and ai.emp_id = el.emp_id
where ai.emp_id is null;
```

Comment: Dear @Gordon, Your query works perfectly. I need to check two more table. One is Exception_entry and another is Leave_entry. I have to  find the emp_id who are not in these two table alse. thanks for ur cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2014-12-09'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2014-12-11'

;WITH MyCte ([Date])
AS
(
    SELECT  [Date] = @StartDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date]) FROM MyCte WHERE [Date] < @EndDate
)
,EmployeeList ([EmpID], [Date])
AS
(
    SELECT 1, '2014-12-11 00:00:00.000' UNION
    SELECT 2, '2014-12-11 00:00:00.000' UNION
    SELECT 4, '2014-12-11 00:00:00.000' UNION
    SELECT 5, '2014-12-11 00:00:00.000' UNION
    SELECT 2, '2014-12-10 00:00:00.000' UNION
    SELECT 4, '2014-12-10 00:00:00.000' UNION
    SELECT 5, '2014-12-10 00:00:00.000' UNION
    SELECT 1, '2014-12-09 00:00:00.000' UNION
    SELECT 2, '2014-12-09 00:00:00.000' UNION
    SELECT 3, '2014-12-09 00:00:00.000'
)
SELECT  DISTINCT E.[EmpID], M.[Date]
FROM    EmployeeList E
CROSS APPLY (SELECT [Date] FROM MyCTE WHERE [Date] NOT IN (SELECT [Date] FROM EmployeeList WHERE EmpID = E.EmpID)) M
```